# PHP deleting variable after new form

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

In my code, I have two forms for users to select options. The first variable will save but as soon as the user submits the second form, the variable from the first form is no longer saved.

```
<div class = "school">
<h3>Please select the university you previously attended</h3>
<form action = "" method = "post" name = "school_form">
<select name="school" size ="10">

<?php
//shows options for $selected_school
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT school FROM data;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // inserts all data as array
  echo "<option>". $row['school'] ."</option>";
      }
 }
?>

</select>
<br>
<input type ="submit" name = "submit_school" value = "Enter">
</form>
<?php
//saves selected option as $selected_school
if(isset($_POST['submit_school'])){
$selected_school = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['school']);
echo "You have selected: " .$selected_school;
}
?>

</div>
<div class ="courses">
<h3>Please select the courses you took</h3>
<form action = "" method ="post" name ="course_form">

<?php
//user shown options for courses
$sql2 = "SELECT transfer_course, transfer_title FROM data WHERE school = ? ORDER BY transfer_course ASC";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
echo "SQL statement failed";
} else {
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $selected_school);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
echo "<input type='checkbox' name ='boxes[]' value = '" . $row2['transfer_course'] . "' >" . $row2['transfer_course'] . "<br>";
      }
 }
?>
<br>
<input type ="submit" name = "submit_courses" value = "Enter">
</form>
<br>
<?php
//saved selected option(s) as $selected_course
if(isset($_POST['submit_courses'])){//to run PHP script on submit
   if(!empty($_POST['boxes'])){
      foreach($_POST['boxes'] as $selected_course){
         echo "You have selected: " . $selected_course . "</br>";
      }
   }
 }
 ?>
 </div>
<div class = "output">
<h3>Course Equivalency</h3>
<?php
$sql3 = "SELECT arcadia_course, arcadia_title FROM data WHERE school = " . $selected_school . " AND transfer_course = " . $selected_course . "";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
if($result3)
{
  while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
    echo $row3['arcadia_course'] . " " . $row3['arcadia_title'] . "<br>";
 }
 } else {
    echo "failed";
    echo $sql3;
}

 ?>
```

So by the time I get to my next sql statement

```
$sql3 = "SELECT arcadia_course, arcadia_title FROM data WHERE school = " . $selected_school . " AND transfer_course = " . $selected_course . "";
```

When the school is selected, it saves the variable, but when the course is selected, $selected_school becomes blank again.

I already have session_start() at the top of the page.

Comment: Where is your form code?

Comment: @Swati its html code I left out for sake of making it simpler to read. I have "<form action = "" method = "post">
<select name="school" size ="10">" and "</select>" around php code

Comment: Your second form needs to pass that `selected_school` variable over in it's post as well (perhaps in a hidden form field). The client here is refreshing the page when the second form is submitted and upon that refresh it has to carry that value through, otherwise it's lost.

Comment: @JNevill how do I do that?

Comment: This is totally old-school and perhaps there are better ways to do this now, but you can use `<input type="hidden">` to hold that value so you can pick it up from the `$_POST[]` when it hits your server. Essentially you are creating HTML sending to the client, the client is using the second form and that all gets submitted via post back to your server. If it isn't in that post or tucked away in the session variable (I would think) then it's lost. Adding a hidden input to the form to hold that value so it makes it back on `POST` should work here. (unless I'm misunderstanding the question).

Comment: @JNevill I changed the second form to type hidden but then it won't actually submit anything. Checkboxes can be checked but then nothing happens and won't output the selected course options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used `session` variable ,it will help to make data accessible across the various pages .

So,whenever form get submitted you can save that value in session and retrieve it anytime.In top of your php file you need to start session i.e `session_start();` .Then in your code

```
<?php
//saves selected option as $selected_school
if(isset($_POST['submit_school'])){
 $_SESSION['selected_school ']=$selected_school;// here you are storing value to session 
$selected_school = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['school']);
echo "You have selected: " .$selected_school;
}
?>
```

Same you can do with your `$selected_course` also .Then you can passed value to your query like below :

```
$sql3 = "SELECT arcadia_course, arcadia_title FROM data WHERE school = " .$_SESSION['selected_school ']. " AND transfer_course = " .$_SESSION['selected_course']. "";
```

For more information refer [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm)

Comment: that still didn't work. It still will save the variable but as soon as I submit the courses, it forgets the value for the school.

Comment: turns out, the $_SESSION['selected_school'] = $selected_school needed to be under the line below it. It works now, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your option doesn't have a value it is passing. Try this in your first form while loop:

```
echo '<option value="' . $row['school'] . '">' . $row['school'] . '</option>';
```

It looks like there may be some more issues you are having as well. If this doesn't fix your issue, I'll dig deeper.

EDIT: Then, yes, as others have suggested, you probably want to add a hidden input field to pass that variable value on the second form submit as well.

What we are saying about the hidden input field is this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selected_school" value="<?php if(isset($selected_school) echo $selected_school; ?>">
```

Comment: putting the value as $row['school'] has it only output the first word. Like if the option was "the school" then it only outputs "the"

Comment: Also the type hidden for the input won't allow the user to actually submit it. The checkboxes will press but then it won't do anything with it until submit is pressed but since it's hidden, there is no submit.

Comment: The php put in the value is first checking if the $selected_school variable is set so it doesn't throw an error on first page load.

Comment: I can't use the type hidden because then it doesn't do anything. I can press the checkboxes but then it doesn't do anything. It doesn't give any output.